# Tinkerpop/Titan/Graph DB: Is storing Map<String,String> to properties faster than edges/vertices with labels?

Tags: performance, graph-databases, titan, tinkerpop

In graph database, namely Titan, I store various data. Some of them tend to create large data sets (10000's), but can be modelled as a Map.

Should I store these maps in vertex properties, using their key:value as key:value of the map,  or rather model them using edge labels (as keys) and vertices' labels (or property entries) as values?

I.e.

```
Vertex { prop1: val1
         prop2: val2 }
```

versus

```
Vertex ----- [prop1] -------> Vertex [val1]
       \-----[prop2] -------> Vertex [val2]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is generally advised to model your data with Titan schema properties.  Typically, the more you can tell Titan about your schema the better it will perform and the more Titan features you can take advantage of.  If you store all of your properties in a single property containing a `Map`, those properties can't be indexed, writing to certain graph formats like GraphML and GML won't be supported, your gremlin won't be quite as fluid because you'll be getting a `Map` of a `Map` from a vertex/edge, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't mean whole map in a single property. I meant one vertex with 10000 properties vs. one vertex with 10000 adjacent vertices. Updated the question.

Comment: If you have a vertex with 10000 properties, I'd think that you likely had a modelling problem.  I would probably look for some design that fits between 10000 properties on a vertex and 10000 adjacent vertices.  If I went with the 10000 adjacent vertices I guess i would consider populating the value of the property on the edge as that would help speed property retrieval and you might find it useful to do some vertex-centric indexing there.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Last thing - regardless of model, what's generally faster? I could try, but I mean for larger data sets.

Comment: I'd only be speculating if I recommended something.  I've not had a production situation with that many properties on a vertex to say.  I think you would have to test it out.